# Selecting Data from 2 tables based on another

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I am using Oracle via the SQL+ command line, i'm trying to display data from two different tables, but i require the use of a third table to determine what to display. Below is an image of my sample 3 tables.

Stack won't let me show my images in the question so here is a link:

[image]

I want to display the "Name","O_ID" and "Date" for each order. I'm quite new to SQL and this may have been answered before but i could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables:

```
SELECT
  c.Name,
  o.O_ID,
  od.Date
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN "Order"   AS o  ON c.C_ID = o.C_ID
INNER JOIN OrderDate AS od ON o.O_ID = od.O_ID;
```

Comment: That worked great, way easier than i was expecting, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: line
INNER JOIN "Order"   AS o  ON c.C_ID = o.O_ID
shouldn't be
INNER JOIN "Order"   AS o  ON c.C_ID = o.C_ID
?

Comment: @AndreuAlcon Yes, it should, you are right. Sorry, fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is a very common practice and requires a INNER JOIN.
From a design perspective, the Order Date table shouldn't even exist. The date column should just reside within the Order table. I wrote the query based on that design:

```
SELECT 
       o.O_ID,
       o.Date,
       c.Name,


FROM
      customer AS c
      INNER JOIN order AS o ON c.C_ID = o.C_ID
```

**Edit:**

More on the issue of your design: A natural ordering of your data would be that there is 1 date for an order, not many dates for an order. Introducing another table to simply store the date allows for there to potentially be many dates associated with an order, which is simply unnatural.

Comment: maybe there are multiple order dates? maybe the order can be added onto.

Comment: @samyi That sounds more like revision history more than adding to an order. In a typical production environment, you would be using audit tables or something like CDC to accomplish this as it is meta data.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you're making assumptions based on what you've seen in the past.  I do agree what you've suggested makes more sense to me as well but each system has their own set of requirements.

Comment: @samyi Fair enough, at the very least at may give the OP some ideas about how to optimize his table arrangements if it is just an issue of design.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN`

```
select c.Name, o.O_ID, od.Date 
from Customer c
inner join Order o on o.O_ID = c.C_ID
inner join OrderDate od on o.O_ID = od_ID
```

Doc: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp